# Javascript percentage calculator adder function not working

Tags: javascript, function, percentage

I'm building a percentage calculator to learn JavaScript. Below is my attempt.

One of the functions works just fine (the one that takes the percentage away from the number), but the one that adds the percentage to the number seems to be adding the values like they are a string.  I've had a look for solutions and using `parseInt()` seems to crop up quite a bit but I can't seem to implement it with my present code so I'm hoping someone can help.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var per = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var num = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var sum = num / 100 * per;
  var output = num - sum;

  console.log(output);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;

}


function myFunction2() {
  var per = document.getElementById("input3").value;
  var num = document.getElementById("input4").value;
  var sum = num / 100 * per;
  var output = sum + num;

  console.log(output);

  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = output;

}
```

```html
<section id="number less percentage"></section>

<h1>Number less percentage</h1>

<input id="input2" placeholder="enter the number"></input>

<input id="input1" placeholder="enter percentage of a number"></input>

<button value='send' id="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Click for 
    result</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</section>

<section id="number plus percentage"></section>

<h1>Number plus percentage</h1>

<input id="input4" placeholder="enter the number"></input>

<input id="input3" placeholder="enter percentage of a number"></input>

<button value='send' id="submit" onclick="myFunction2()">Click for 
    result</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>

</section>
```

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is the invalid HTML. `<input>` does not have a closing tag (so no need for `</input>`) and you have an extra `</section>` right after your opening tag.

Comment: `var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input4").value);`

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey I'll tidy that up!

Comment: Thank you @Barmar very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a bit funny when it comes to numbers and addition. For example:

```js
'20' - '30' === 10      // `-` always coerces operands to numbers
'20' + '30' === '2030'  // `+` with strings is interpreted as concatenation
```

The values returned from `document.getElementById` are strings, so it's better to parse them **all** (even the one that works) to numbers before proceeding with the addition or subtraction. Your code can be:

```js
function calculate() {
  var per = parseInt(document.getElementById('input1').value);
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('input2').value);

  var sum = (num / 100) * per;
  var output = num - sum;

  console.log(output);

  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = output;
}

function myFunction2() {
  var per = parseInt(document.getElementById('input3').value);
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('input4').value);

  var sum = (num / 100) * per;
  var output = sum + num;

  console.log(output);

  document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: The problem is with `num`, not `per`.

Comment: Yes, I just chose 'per' as an example of how to convert strings to numbers, then added more detailed comment as to why num is performing a string concat and not an addition.

Comment: Awesome thanks for such a prompt answer @KevinB!